# Minix installation ERROR ٍ"Active partition"

Tags: system-installation, minix

I downloaded Minix 3 from [here](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=www:download:start) and wrote it on a USB flash drive using Rufus (in Windows os).
When it boots it says :

```
->NETBSD MBR boot
->Errror No active partition
```

I searched for "active partition" in google and found 2 ways to solve this problem using a live Linux. One of which is this:

```
->sudo fdisk /dev/sdxy 
->use the "a" option
->and then "w" it
```

The other way is using Gparted in Ubuntu (in "Ubuntu live")
and then:

```
->Right-click the Primary partition you wish to make Active and select Manage Flags.
->In Manage Flags on ..., tick (to enable) the boot check box to make the
```

partition Active.

but none of this ways worked and I still have the problem. My laptop is LGX13.

(However, this does not make any difference because I booted Minix on my other laptops and still problem was there).

Have anyone else had this problem?

How did you solve it?

Is there any other way to activate a partition?

Comment: Actually both of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a CD/DVD instead of a USB flash drive. As it is written in minix3 official website, it can't be booted through a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I actually encountered this error today, too. Any Linux distribution usually supports installation from a USB drive so I assumed Minix3 would do so, too. But that is *not* the case! [This link](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=usersguide:x86usbworkaround) provides a detailed description of a workaround, though. Taken from that source:

> First step: make a bootable USB of your favorite Linux or *BSD flavor, in which you > can install Qemu. USB persistency is recommended, though normal USB without
> persistency can also be used if Qemu can be installed on RAM, as Qemu isn't necessary
> after a successful installation.
>
> Second step: boot the target machine with your live USB, set up the network, then
> download and install Qemu. Alternatively, if there are network issues with the live
> USB, Qemu can be installed by downloading its packages or sources separately, along
> with the Minix ISO (see below), and then copied to the bootable USB disk. Don't worry,
> an Internet connection won't be necessary during the MINIX install.
>
> Third step: download the Minix ISO and save it in your
> persistent USB or any normal FAT USB. If there are network issues, download it before
> the second step (as mentioned above). Save it as normal ISO file. You're now ready to
> perform the installation.
>
> Issue the following command: You will have to customize the command for your
> bootable USB platform. Be patient, as it may be very slow if not used in conjunction
> with KVM:

`qemu-system-i386 -m 512 -drive file=/dev/wd0c,format=raw,media=disk -cdrom /tmp/minix_R3.3.0.iso -boot d &`

Again, refer to the link for a more detailed explanation. I just included this long quote in case the link might be dead in the future.